# How to drop unnecessary rows and fill them correctly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
overflow_data={'state': ['CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'HI', 'HI', 'HI', 'HI', 'HI', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY',], 
'year':  [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
'value1':  [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 8, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 7, np.nan],
'value2':  [15, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12, np.nan, np.nan, 14, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 20, np.nan, 10, np.nan]}
test_df =pd.DataFrame(overflow_data)
test_df
```

[image]

I would like to fill the prior rows with data from the previous years, if they exist. My first thought was to use:

```
test_df.ffill()
```

However, the data looks like this then, where the data is filled with the wrong state data if the earlier years don't exist (for example, values for Hawaii in 2010 and 2011 are filled with California's earlier data:

[image]

Ideally, I would like something like this, where the years before the first data entry for the state are dropped and the rest of the rows are filled in correctly, so it will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could forward fill on a groupby and then drop the reamining null values :

```
test_df.update(test_df.groupby(["state"]).ffill())

test_df.dropna()

state   year    value1  value2
0   CA  2010    1.0     15.0
1   CA  2011    1.0     15.0
2   CA  2012    1.0     15.0
3   CA  2013    1.0     15.0
4   CA  2014    3.0     12.0
7   HI  2012    8.0     14.0
8   HI  2013    8.0     14.0
9   HI  2014    8.0     14.0
11  NY  2011    4.0     20.0
12  NY  2012    4.0     20.0
13  NY  2013    7.0     10.0
14  NY  2014    7.0     10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby()` and `fillna()` will give you the result you are looking for:

```
res = test_df.groupby("state").apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='backfill')).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you also want to loose trailing *".0"*:

```
res = res.astype({'value1': 'int32', 'value2': 'int32'})

res
Out[2]: 
   state  year  value1  value2
0     CA  2010       1      15
1     CA  2011       3      12
2     CA  2012       3      12
3     CA  2013       3      12
4     CA  2014       3      12
5     HI  2010       8      14
6     HI  2011       8      14
7     HI  2012       8      14
8     NY  2010       4      20
9     NY  2011       4      20
10    NY  2012       7      10
11    NY  2013       7      10
```